# Why jQuery consider an 200 response Ajax request with empty content as fail()?

Tags: jquery

First, there's no cross-region problem at all.

I found if the server response an empty content body, jQuery consider this as fail()?

Why is this?

Comment: it looks like a parse error... can you add a error handler like `error: function (jqXhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
    }
`

Comment: any browser console errors?

Comment: What `dataType` are you using?

Comment: @Wynand application/json

Comment: @karthikr no error. just no execution of get callback, but trigger fail() instead

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're using jQuery >= 1.9 an empty JSON response will be rejected, according to the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax):

> The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of `null` or `{}` instead.

Answer (score 15):

WynandB is correct, however there is an alternate resolution: have the server return `HTTP 204 No Content` instead, which will make jQuery ignore the parsing error.